# Adding Values from Data Table to Another Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add values from Datatable1 to Datatable2 using asp.net c#.

I just don't know the which path i shoud follow.

[image]

What should i use for it ?

Comment: What types are Datatables?

Comment: I assume these are `System.Data.DataTable` instances. If table1 had unknown ID's you would also add them to the final result? So similar to a FULL OUTER JOIN in sql?

Comment: is the position of the data always the same?. is SQ, KB and XG always in the same place?

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25449317/637840